# Shopping cart pricing rule condition is not visible on orders total in order page

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, frontend, shopping-cart-price-rules

**Shopping Cart Pricing rule** logic applied successfully but not visible on orders total in order page,

[image]

**FYI** Front end showing the Shopping Cart Pricing rule,

[image]

> How to get Shopping Cart Pricing rule on orders total in order page?

Comment: is the discount showing in the cart? is this a custom design package?

Comment: Yes, the discount showing in the cart and this is not Custom design package, simply shopping cart pricing rule. @jscar

Comment: What kind of shopping cart rule is that which adds some charge on top? Can you put the settings of that rule into your question?

Comment: Please make sure you don't have any third party module that overrides your admin order page

Comment: @magefms Is any best way can i find which is the file override, i have lot of extensions.

Comment: I think the most possible extension to override it is a Shipping Method Extension or otherwise anything that has something to do in checkout steps in checkout page

Comment: like a third party payment extension

Comment: @magefms    Still not find an error, and keep searching where is the error, and also cross check with shipping and payment module.

Comment: is special handling charges, is the one not visible?

Comment: tried to replicate it on my machine and everything works

Comment: In standard Magento a cart rule applies a discount (i.e. the total amount is reduced). In your case you add some fee, therefore it's most probably some custom functionality implied there (not an usual cart rule) which is not added in the usual total calculation in admin.

Comment: @HelgeB I am using a couple of extensions like payment fees(https://github.com/devromans/payment-fee) and extra charge fees(https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee) and for shipping using WebShopApps MatrixRates.

Comment: @magefms FYI - I am using a couple of extensions like payment fees(https://github.com/devromans/payment-fee) and extra charge fees(https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee) and for shipping using WebShopApps MatrixRates.

Comment: Hi @Gem , it kind of work for me. can you try to reinstall the module by just overwriting its files with the original files from the package

Comment: @Gem did it work?

Comment: @magefms Yes i did everything, but no use. keep trying myself.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the modules you share in the link and everything works well for me

Comment: did you try to reinstall ?

Comment: Yes i did, if i test with localhost its working.

Comment: @HelgeB I just want to clarify, the extension working good in localhost, in live working partially(working but not visible on orders total in order page). My question is why the error or exception not raised, I mean no error message in logs, is there any manual trigger required?

Comment: @magefms I just want to clarify, the extension working good in localhost, in live working partially(working but not visible on orders total in order page). My question is why the error or exception not raised, I mean no error message in logs, is there any manual trigger required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91544/discussion-between-gem-and-magefms).